# Python Scrips on Raspberry - ssh works, cronjob doesn't

Tags: ssh, cron, raspberry-pi, smtp

I wrote a `python` script that checks a website and eventually sends an email. I copied the script to my raspberry and when I execute it via `ssh` it works fine. But when I let it execute by the crontab it doesn't. In the syslog I can see that the script was executed but I get these errors:

```
Apr  2 14:25:01 raspberrypi CRON[28850]: (pi) CMD (sudo /usr/bin/python3 /home/pi/Desktop/Script/main.py >> /home/pi/Desktop/Script/log.txt)
Apr  2 14:25:04 raspberrypi sSMTP[28854]: Unable to connect to "smtp.cablelink.at" port 587.
Apr  2 14:25:04 raspberrypi sSMTP[28854]: Cannot open smtp.cablelink.at:587
Apr  2 14:25:04 raspberrypi cron[430]: sendmail: Cannot open smtp.cablelink.at:587
Apr  2 14:25:04 raspberrypi CRON[28849]: (pi) MAIL (mailed 220 bytes of output but got status 0x0001 from MTA#012)
```

The crontab entry looks like this:

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/python3 /home/pi/Desktop/Scrabber/main.py >> /home/pi/Desktop/Scrabber/log.txt
```

I think it's not a problem of permission because for all i can see the crontab is executed as user `pi` as well as when I use the `ssh` command.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I believe this has more to do with your mail setup than with your cron schedule.  If you log in via SSH, you say that the mail is sent without issues?

Comment: Yes when i do it via ssh it works perfect. And also receive the email.

Answer (score 0):

just found out whats going on. The problem was that in my python script i had a link which was name open('logfile.txt'). When i used the ssh it worked but the cronjob needed the full path like open('home/..../logfile.txt').

Now it works!! YEAH